# Site collection title in breadcrumb

Tags: 2010, site-collection, breadcrumb

My breadcrumb is displaying my site collection title instead of my RootWeb title. How can I display the RootWeb title? Or how can I change my site collection title?

Comment: Do you have a portal connection set up? Site Collections do not have a name per se, they are just logical containers, the RootWeb should only be the site with a title showing, unless you have a portal site connection enabled, in which case it may be showing the title of the portal's RootWeb.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by James Love, your site collection would use the title of the rootweb.  You could use a tool like SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/) to view the properties of the rootweb to ensure the Title and Name properties are correct.